# ¿Porque mi galería de imágenes funciona en desktop pero no en modo responsivo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

Actualmente tengo una galería de imágenes que funciona perfectamente cuando la visualizo mediante una pantalla de *pc* o *laptop* e inclusive una *tablet*, pero el problema viene cuando quiero visualizarla a la medida en un dispositivo **móvil** ya que simplemente desaparece:

```js
// Esta parte del código hace que funcione correctamente la galería
function slideShow() {
  document.getElementById('Galeria').src = imgArray[curIndex];
  curIndex++;
  if (curIndex == imgArray.length) {
    curIndex = 0;
  }
  setTimeout("slideShow()", imgDuration);
}
```

```css
#Galeria {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-6 hidden-lg hidden-md contenedores" id="contenedorGaleria">
  <center>
    <img class="img-responsive" id="Galeria" />
  </center>
</div>
```

**Nota:** esto funciona en pantallas *laptop*, *desktop* y *tablets* pero no en **móviles**.

Comment: ¿No será que estas pasando la funcion en el setTimeout como string?

Comment: @B.Pato A setTimeout se le puede pasar como parámetro un string que será evaluado (y por ello puede sufrir los mismos problemas y vulnerabilidades que el `eval` y no es muy recomendado).

Comment: @David lee sobre cómo crear un [mcve] y edita la pregunta para añadir uno y que podamos reproducir el problema para ayudarte de forma más efectiva.

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de probarlo en el móvil (Android 5.1.1 y firefox) y me funciona solo he tenido que declarar a mayores un array con la localización de las imagenes, la posición de inicio del array, el tiempo que se muestran y añadir un evento que lance la función despues de que este cargado el bloque de la galeria.

No tengo conocimientos de bootstrap, no se si lo he añadido correctamente, lo único que veo que afecta la visibilidad son las clases hidden.
[Bootstrap Example](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_hlp_text-hidden&stacked=h)

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html> 
        <head>
            <title>Titulo de la web</title>
            <style>
                #Galeria {
                  width: 100%;
                  height: 100%;
                  margin: auto;
                }
            </style>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script>
                //var imgArray = ["imagen01.jpg","https://web.com/imagen02.jpg","imagen03.jpg"];
                var imgArray = ["https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1e/Wikipedia-logo-v2-es.svg/1200px-Wikipedia-logo-v2-es.svg.png","https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1f/Wikipedia_mini_globe_handheld.jpg"];
                var curIndex = 0;
                var imgDuration = 3000;
                function slideShow() {
                    document.getElementById('Galeria').src = imgArray[curIndex];
                    curIndex++;
                    if (curIndex == imgArray.length) {
                        curIndex = 0;
                    } 
                    setTimeout("slideShow()", imgDuration);
                }
                
                window.addEventListener('load',slideShow);
            </script>
        </head>
        <body class="container-fluid">
            <div class="col-xs-6 hidden-lg hidden-md contenedores" id="contenedorGaleria">
                <center>
                    <img class="img-responsive" id="Galeria" />
                </center>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: col-xs-6 

Y si importas los cdn de bootstrap y lo metes en un row HASTA quizás funcione...